# Hover Over Text in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Wondering if there's a way to make a text bubble show up when the user hovers over a metric in a Power BI report.

I have tried using alt text, but that does not show up anywhere.

Comment: Are you talking about a particular visual? Some of them have tooltip fields that pop up on hover.

Comment: I'd like this for the scorecards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, I don't think this is possible natively.

There are some ideas related to this that you can vote for:

[Custom Alt Text (tooltip) On Hover Over Any Visual](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/31501933-custom-alt-text-tooltip-on-hover-over-any-visual)

[Tooltip for Matrix visual (and others)](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/31511665-tooltip-for-matrix-visual-and-others)

[Tooltips for Tables](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/30979345-tooltips-for-tables)

There is also a [Dynamic Tooltip custom visual](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380983) that you might be close enough to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem just now, and the documentation page [Create tooltips based on report pages in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-tooltips) describes how to do this. Probably this functionality was not around in March 2018 (when the accepted answer was posted).

## Steps

In summary the steps are as follows (assuming you already have a visualization):

1. Create a new page, name it `Tooltip 1`
2. On the `Tooltip 1` page, go to Format → Page Information and switch on the Tooltip toggle
3. Go to Canvas settings and set the Type to `Tooltip`.
4. Create a text box via Home → Text box, fill it with the text you want to show when one hovers over your visualization.
5. Select your visualization
6. Click on Format → Tooltip
7. Set Type to `Report page`
8. Set Page to `Tooltip 1`

Now when you hover over the visualization, the text box from step 4 will be shown.

## Additions

- You can mark the page `Tooltip 1` as hidden, such that it does not show up as a tab on your report.
- You can also customize the tooltip size by setting the Page size of the tooltip page to `Custom` with suitable width and height values.
- As described in the link, instead of text you can also create a whole visualization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transparent shape as an overlay on the text you want the hover over test to appear on

Turn Action On

Type Page Navigation

Destination None

Tooltip - Add the test you want to display on the hover